# how to sort list in alphabetical order in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a program where I take in a txt file and break up the text into individual words and puts them into a list. the next part is to sort the list alphabetically and print it.

so far I have a text file that just says:
 "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

and my program so far looks like:

```
file = input("Enter File Name: ")
myList =[]

readFile = open(file, 'r')

for line in readFile:
    myList.append(line.split(" "))

myList.sort()

print(myList)
```

the problem is that when I run the program the list is being created and filled with each word but when it is printed out it is not being sorted in alphabetical order. I also tried `print(myList.sort())` and the only thing that prints is "none"

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `line.split(" ")` creates a list of words in `line`, but `myList.append` adds this list to myList as a new **single** item (so you end up with a list of lists rather than list of words). What you probably wanted is:

```
myList.extend(line.split(" "))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read the whole file rather than one line at a time:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    words = f.read().split()
words.sort()
```

This uses the default for `split` which splits on a space, line break or any other whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

From what I observed the problem is your list of words is in a list,

myList = [["the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]].

So instead of

```
for line in readFile:
    myList.append(line.split(" "))
```

You should be writing

```
for line in readFile:
    myList = line.split(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The extend property works:

```
filename = open(input("Enter the input file name: "))
myList =[]
for line in filename:
    myList.extend(line.split(" "))
myList.sort()
print(myList)
```

Answer (score -3):

Python has two sorting functions - one which sorts the list in-place, which is what you are expecting in your code, and one which leaves the original list intact and returns a sorted list (which is what you are using).  iirc the other function is called "sorted" - but now you have the info you need to look it up.  This is probably also a previously asked question in stackoverflow, I encourage you look for and to link to the other ones.